# Check structure fields for being non-initial?

Tags: abap

I need to fetch records from csv file and process it. Initially I need to check if all the values are there or not (around 15 fields), if the value is initial (i.e. blank) I need to throw the error (output has to be written in a file for each record).

Current logic I am following is :

```
LOOP AT gt_filedata into gs_filedata.

  IF gs_filedata-var1 IS INITIAL.
     concatenate gv_msg text-001 into gv_msg SEPARATED BY ','.
  ENDIF.
  IF gs_filedata-var2 IS INITIAL.
     concatenate gv_msg text-002 into gv_msg SEPARATED BY ','.
  ENDIF.
  " And so on...

ENDLOOP.
```

I need to know if there any function module or any other way to optimize my code and improve its performance.

Comment: What leads you to believe that you need to do so? Do you have an actual problem?

Comment: I feel that instead of repeating the same logic,we could write a perform or call a function module(if any) to improve code readability and re-usability.

Comment: @vwegert my last two developments were similar,fetching data from csv file...validating and processing it.I thought that writing a generic perform/FM/static method would help me/colleagues to reuse the same.I am newbie to abap ,so not sure about the performance.would be great if you can guide me.Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: for a generic approach wrapped in a FM you can use the class cl_abap_typedescr and its method describe_by_data to get the components of your structure, then loop over all components, assign the current component to a field symbol and check if it is initial. That way your generic FM doesn't need to know the structure it has to check in advance. But as you have to do that loop and assign for each row i seriously doubt it is going to be any faster than the manual approach.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming, as your code indicates, that you want to *produce*, not to *fetch* (as you wrote) a csv line:

```
field-symbols: <lv_part> type any,
               <ls_filedata> like line of gt_filedata.
data: lv_part type string,
      lv_msg  type string.
loop at gt_filedata assigning <ls_filedata>.
  clear lv_msg.
  do.
    assign component sy-index of structure <ls_filedata> to <lv_part>.
    if sy-subrc ne 0.
      exit. " exit DO
    endif.
    if <lv_part> is not initial.
      lv_part = <lv_part>.  " Converts to type C
      if lv_msg is not initial.
        concatenate lv_msg ',' into lv_msg.
      endif.
      concatenate lv_msg lv_part into lv_msg.
    endif.
  enddo.
  append lv_msg to lt_csv.  " Or transfer line to output file here
endloop.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want not to check each workarea field via `IF`, you should  read the dd03 from the type of the workarea. Then you need some hard coded strings, which partially identify those fields in the workarea. Then you need an inner loop where you loop over the dd03 workarea, with a "contains pattern" instruction previously, which guarantees, that You loop only over the relevant field names of the dd03. Then you need `assign-component (inner loop over dd03l-fieldnameof-actual looped field) of structure YourWorkarea to <anyfieldsymbol>`, which you created before.

If you use "casting" afterwards you can use rollname to cast the actual looped field to rollname which is a part of dd03l. This quarantees that a fieldsymbol typed by "any" can properly be filled and therefore checked for being initial more precisely.

Do you need some code? Here it is:

1. Define some variables:

   ```
   lo_structdesc    TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
   dfies_wa  TYPE  dfies,
   dfies_tab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF  dfies,
   lv_ident  TYPE fieldname value 'INP_'.    " imagine all fields start like this.
   FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fsany>  TYPE any.
   FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fsanyv> TYPE any
   ```
2. Imagine you want to get the datatype of Your workarea ( there are several ways):

   ```
   " get struct by type
   lo_structdesc ?=  cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_data( my_struct ).
   " introspect components   
   dfies_tab = lo_structdesc->GET_DDIC_FIELD_LIST( ).
   loop at dfies_tab into dfies_wa where fieldname cp lv_ident.
   assign-component ( dfies_wa-fieldname ) of structure my_struct to <fsany> casting type  (dfies_wa-rollname).
      if <fsany> is assigned.
          if <fsany> is initial.
             " ERROR HERE
          else.
             " continue with loop.
          endif.
      endif.
   ```

   endloop.

Untested shrunk copy out of my source for dynamic where statement creation, cut down to the most fitting parts, removed overhead, so untested.